# Carousel Forcing to Update Cached Images

Tags: c#, uwp, carousel

I am using the C# UWP Carousel to show a collection of images.  The images are thumbnails of a 3d viewer viewpoint.  When I click save viewpoint it updates the image of that position the first time.  However when I click successive saves it doesn't update the image in the control.  The path to the image has not changed but the contents of the image has.   I have manually verified that the image files are indeed getting updated.  Just the image on the carousel is not.  How do I force the Carousel Control to update all images or clear its cache forcing an update?

I have tried setting the ItemSource to null and resetting it. but that doesn't work.  There has to be a way to tell the control to refresh the graphics.  UpdateLayout doesn't work and when I trigger the CollectionChanged event it doesn't work either.

```
      mCarouselControl.ItemsSource = null;
        mCarouselControl.Items.Clear();
```

Update the thumbnail images
then

mCarouselControl.ItemsSource = mCaroselItems;

HERE IS HOW YOU FIX THE PROBLEM
In the bitmaps that you are loading for the thumbnails you HAVE to set the bitmap create options to IgnoreImageCache.

```
    public async Task<BitmapImage> LoadThumbnailFromFile(string filepath)
    {
        var bi = new BitmapImage();

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filepath);
        const uint requestedSize = 400;
        const ThumbnailMode thumbnailMode = ThumbnailMode.PicturesView;
        const ThumbnailOptions thumbnailOptions = ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail;

        StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(thumbnailMode, requestedSize, thumbnailOptions);

        bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        bi.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
        bi.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
        bi.SetSource(thumbnail);
        return bi;
    }
```

Comment: You need to include some code for what you have tried

Comment: Currently what I am trying is the following.